# How Liferay Login works?

Tags: java, ajax, authentication, liferay, portal

I have put my Liferay behind a proxy server. There is one issue at the login page. When I login it does not refresh to show me the logged in state. Rather it stays on the login form.

Can anyone help regarding this?

Comment: Could you explain your setup? What proxy server are you using? Is it used as a cache-proxy? For SSL offloading? Or loadbalancing (is there more than one liferay instance running)?

Comment: It is IIS 8.5. It is used for security purposes to only allow traffic to backend via IIS.

Comment: I got this resolve though yesterday, but disabling the cache settings in IIS 8.5. I found at one forum about it and applied that fix and it resolved that.

Otherwise I was getting 304 not modified response header.